# xcode4.2 - Swift Accessing Viewcontrollers label from external class

Tags: swift, inheritance, viewcontroller, xcode4.2

Where is the problem accessing a ViewController: UIViewController label (here: outlet called *timerLabel*)from AnotherClass. I would like to set a text.

```
class AnotherClass{

//[...]

 func updateTimeLabel(){
        // To Solve!!!*******
        //class name is ViewController?

    let myLabel = ViewController.timerLabel
    myLabel.text = "HiDuEi"
}

//[...]

// error message is:

//Instance member 'timerLabel' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

}
```

how can I access the ViewController class (called *ViewController*) properly and access my outlet (a label) there, called *timerLabel*?
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewController` is a type, not an instance of the object. You need to somehow get a reference to your **ViewController instance** and then access the label. E.g.

```
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.timerLabel.text = "HiDuEi"
```

Note that this above creates a new instance, it's hard to say where your other viewController is created and how to access it from the code you posted.

Comment: Done! I forgot the () after the ViewController as I tried this before. THX so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

**With the explanation of your question seems like, 
You have an IBOutlet (which can only be accessed with Instance) and you are trying to access it via Class (ViewController)**

*Create an object of ViewController and then try to update the text for timerLabel*

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.timerLabel.text = "HiDuEi"
```

Comment: Thanks so much Deepak, its the old little thing of using the () corectly...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a delegate for the class like

```
class ExternalClass{
   weak var delegate:VCName?
    func updateTimeLabel(){
    // To Solve!!!******* 
      delegate?.timerLabel.text = "HiDuEi" 
    }
 }
```

When create

```
 let ca = ExternalClass()
 ca.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an identifier to the view controller you are trying to access the label from, instantiate it, then access the label, like so:

```
var vc : ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("abc") as! ViewController
vc.timerLabel.text = "HiDuEi"
```

where "abc" is the identifier you used